# Index out of range when paging using gridview asp.net

Tags: c#, gridview

```
int index = -1;
foreach (GridViewRow gvrow in lstHoliday.Rows)
{
    index = (int)lstHoliday.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value;
    bool result = ((CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("Selector")).Checked;
}
```

**Get an error here:**

```
index = (int)lstHoliday.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value;

Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index
```

What am I doing wrong here?

[image]

Comment: cant you just use int index = 0;

Comment: what is the size of lstHoliday.Rows? "gvrow.RowIndex" must be returning a negative or outOfBounds index value

Comment: Another thins is: always put brackets on the value you'll cast to int or whatever. Such as (int)(lstHoliday.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value)

Comment: lstHoliday.Rows count is 8

Comment: @IsmetAlkan tried that it didnt work

Comment: check the lstHoliday.DataKeys's length please.

Comment: so u didnt mentioned the DataKey on your markup?

Comment: i updated the answer so that it will benefit others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `DataKeyNames` property of `GridView` on the markup needs to be mentioned. It wasnt mentioned above which caused the error.

More on [DataKeyNames](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23833/DataKeyNames)

Comment: index is assigned to here as I see. It's not used to point to an index. That shouldn't cause any errors. Am I wrong?

Comment: whats the DataKey that u have mentioned.

Comment: @IsmetAlkan he initialised his variable to a negative number which wasnt necessary.

Comment: That's right but this isn't the real cause to the problem. gvrow.RowIndex is.